# Modify duration of a video with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I have an mp4 video that is 3 minutes long and this is seen in the duration column of Windows explorer and also in video players like VLC.
I want cheat windows explorer and vlc:
Using ffmpeg, is it possible to modify the mp4 file duration metadata to 120 minutes and end after 3 minutes when I play it ?
How would that command be written ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about MP4, and I don't know if ffmpeg is able do this modification, but most video formats have a "duration" field in their header. Changing it should fool video players to assume a wrong duration.